# What does the homomorphism $\rho: \mathbb Z[X] \longrightarrow \mathbb R$, $X\longmapsto 1+\sqrt2$ describe?

Tags: polynomials, ring-homomorphism

Is it the set of all polynomials with integer coefficients, where one then "plugs in" $1+\sqrt2$?

For example: $$a_nX^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1X+a_0$$ becomes $$a_n(1+\sqrt2)^n+a_{n-1}(1+\sqrt2)^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1(1+\sqrt2)+a_0$$

or something different?

Comment: Sometimes some notation makes thing harder to understand. If that homomorphism were described as $$\rho:\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb R\;,\;\;\rho(f(x)):=f\left(1+\sqrt2\right)\;$$ I think seeing that it is the evaluation homomorphism would be much clearer and easier to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you've described is the correct interpretation.